# how to remove duplicates in SAS data step

Tags: duplicates, sas, datastep

How to remove duplicates in SAS data step.

```
data uscpi;
      input year month cpi;
   datalines;
   1990  6 129.9
   1990  7 130.4
   1990  8 131.6
   1990  9 132.7
   1991  4 135.2
   1991  5 135.6
   1991  6 136.0
   1991  7 136.2
   ;
   run;

PROC SORT DATA = uscpi OUT = uscpi_dist NODUPKEY; 
 BY year ; 
 RUN;
```

i can with proc step, but how to remove it in data step. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a way to do it with hash objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5705176/17743

Comment: Which ones do you wanna keep? Just doing it by 'year' will randomly remove records. I dont think that is what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `first.` & `last.` automatic variables created by SAS when using `by-group` processing. They give more control on which row you consider as duplicate.
Please read the manual to [understand by group processing in a Data Step](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001283274.htm)

```
 data uscpi_dedupedByYear;
 set uscpi_sorted;
 by year;
 if first.year; /*only keep the first occurence of each distinct year.  */
 /*if last.year; */ /*only keep the last occurence of each distinct year*/

 run;
```

A lot depends on who your input dataset is sorted. For ex: If your input dataset is sorted by year & month and you use `if first.year;` then you can see that it only keeps the earliest month in any given year. However, if your dataset is sorted by `year & descending month` then `if first.year;` retains last month in any given year.

This behaviour obviously differs from how `nodupkey`  works.